# Get a Image from Google Images for background

Tags: javascript, php, image, google-image-search

i've got code like this, but I want to take images from google images, not from flickr. Is it possible?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var keyword = "mountains";

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
        {
            tags: keyword,
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        },
        function(data) {
            var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length);

            var image_src = data.items[rnd]['media']['m'].replace("_m", "_b");

            $('body').css('background-image', "url('" + image_src + "')");

        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use google image API ( if exist) instead of flicker API.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage a service like SerpAPI to crawl Google search results:
https://serpapi.com/images-results

Using SerpAPI, you can get a JSON response with the image URLs. Two things to note:

- You'll be hotlinking images directly from Google. Some images may not work if they disabling hotlinking
- The images that you display may not be scaled to the proper size (imagine using a 1200px image for a 150px thumbnail)

## Transforming the images

If you want more control over the images, you can leverage a service like imgix or Cloudinary which can either proxy or host the image for you. You would then:

1. Leverage something like SerpAPI to get a JSON response with image URLs
2. Use the URL to pass to an image rendering service. imgix example:
   https://webproxybryan.imgix.net/https%3A%2F%2Fsearchengineland.com%2Ffigz%2Fwp-content%2Fseloads%2F2015%2F12%2Fgoogle-amp-fast-speed-travel-ss-1920-800x450.jpg?w=600&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=3e27b1f48a74c13608cb22b1bafafa87

   - The URL is URI encoded in the above example and signed. Parameters are also added to transform the image via the imgix URL API
3. Display this URL in your application/website

With either imgix or Cloudinary, you can optimize the images for your site and transform them on demand. Just be wary of your usage since you wouild be billed for using either service versus hotlinking the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect images from anywhere, Google included, and store them on Cloudinary. Cloudinary can host the images for you, so that all you need is the URL linking that particular image in your account. This will keep it stable, in case a particular site on Google images changes their images while your application is running.

https://cloudinary.com/